# Gulp 'start' creating errors instead of creating a 'DIst' folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

When initiating Gulp start it's expected a Dist folder be created and a watch to begin on the included dependencies–but instead–it errors out on the 'css' concat.

- I've tried creating the Dist folder manually
- created a test.css file in the src directory

It hasn't made a difference. The same error pops up and nothing else happens.

The tutorial I'm following :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9ZngMW80-k&t=1s
with the expected result seen at time index 37:48. Here is my result ...

**ERROR**

> $ gulp start [05:06:38] Using gulpfile
>   ~/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/gulpfile.js [05:06:38] Starting
>   'start'... [05:06:38] Starting 'build'... [05:06:38] Starting 'css'...
>   [05:06:38] 'css' errored after 12 ms [05:06:38] ReferenceError: concat
>   is not defined
>       at Gulp. (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/gulpfile.js:14:11)
>       at module.exports (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
>       at Gulp. (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/gulpfile.js:39:8)
>
> ```
> at module.exports (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
> at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
> at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
> at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/ChazOSX/OneDrive/~webDev/chazSutherland/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
> ```
>
> [05:06:38] Finished 'build' after 14 ms [05:06:38] Finished 'start'
>   after 27 ms

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

const scripts = require('./scripts');
const styles = require('./styles');

var devMode = false;

gulp.task('css', function(){
  gulp.src(styles)
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('js', function(){
  gulp.src(scripts)
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('./src/html/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('build', function(){
  gulp.start(['css', 'js', 'html']);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
  browserSync.init(null, {
    open: false,
    server: {
      baseDir: 'dist'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('start', function(){
  devMode = true;
  gulp.start(['build', 'browser-sync']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/css/**/*.css'], ['css']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*.js'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/html/**/*.html'], ['html']);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "chazsutherland",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Practice practice practice!!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "make test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "(https://github.com/CyberGolem/learningGulp.com)"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "npm"
  ],
  "author": "Chaz Sutherland",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.2",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

**styles.json**

```
[
  "./src/css/**/*.css"
]
```

**scripts.json**

```
[
  "./node_modules/angular/angular.js",
  "./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js",
  "./src/js/**/*.js"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells you the cause:

> ReferenceError: concat is not defined at Gulp.

You're trying to reference a `concat` variable which isn't defined in your script.

```
const gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
// ...
.pipe(concat('main.css'))
// ...
.pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
```

Just rename the `gulpConcat` constant to `concat` and the error will be fixed. In the video you mentioned, [the declaration is added at 22:27](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9ZngMW80-k&t=22m27s).

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are requiring gulp concat as

`const gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');`

But then later you are trying to use it as `.pipe(concat('main.css'))`

The error is telling you that `concat` is not defined at line 14, and that is true, because you define `gulpConcat` instead of `concat`

So for solution change:

`const gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');` to 
`const concat = require('gulp-concat');`